# Bootstrap Accordion: Open Panel on Arrival

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a Call to Action button at the top of a page. It links to a position further down the page, where I have a Bootstrap Accordion. Is it possible to make the first panel of the accordion open when you arrive there by clicking the CTA button?

Comment: can´t you create your accordion with the first panel already opened by default ? see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: If your accordion is closed by default, you can use jQuery to target the `<div>` panel with a click event and add the `in` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Bootstrap 3 Collapse (I think you said about this). Just use a reference to your collapse ID on your button. See the example:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
</a>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="well">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read the bootstrap page and loot this example:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse